# Selective repeat protocol for file transferring

Tags: c, protocols

Could you please help me with an algorithm for selective repeat protocol file transferring good documentation?Is there any book for protocol programming just like Beej guide for Network Socket Programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the TCP RFCs
I believe [this one](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2018.txt) is the one you want.

You could also pick up a textbook on networking:
[Computer Network: A Top Down Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132856204) is a pretty good one (I've taken a few networking courses and that's been the best one thus far).

Also, google is your friend!

Answer (score 0):

And I think this Interactive Demo can be very helping for understanding the behavior of **Selective Repeat** and GO BACK N

[Selective Repeat / Go Back N  |  CCS-LABS](http://www.ccs-labs.org/teaching/rn/animations/gbn_sr/)